# Data not Visible on Asp.Net MVC3 UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

What I am Trying:

Pass id to Controller get Results and Display results in UI with Asp.Net MVC3 / JQuery

What I Did:

I have a contoller(`[HttpPost] Index(Int? id)`) which reurns listDetails to view

I have a textbox which passes id through jquery to controller Index and gets listDetails as model to View

Now I am trying to display `@Model.xyz.Name`

I tried debugging code with a breakpoint and model in controller, and it gets valid data.

I tried breakpoint in view and it gets data.

But when I run the application Data is not at all visible on UI.
Can some one suggest me where I am going wrong?

controller code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}



 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id.HasValue)
            {
get list of values
  return View(listOfValues);
}
```

view Code

```
 @if (@Model != null)
            {
                @Model.Person.DisplayName
            }
```

Jquery Code with Auto Complete(triggering select)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {

        $("#tbxSearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Details/GetSearchData", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term, maxResults: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.label, value: item.label, id: item.value }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                //alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.id)
                //      : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                $.ajax({ url: 'PersonDetails',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id: ui.item.id
                    },
                    async: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                       // alert("Success");
                        //$('#DivDetails').show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the using statement at the top of the view? Is it IEnumerable? It looks like you are returning a list of Person.

Try to say foreach(var item in Model) ... and see if you see anything.

Comment: I tried Debugging code in View. It shows value in @Model.xyz.Name